# How to put all values in the first row into an array?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set my array equal to all column headers of tables in a worksheet.

If I were doing this in Excel, I would click on `A1` and do Control+Shift+Right Arrow. I've found some 15 year old code attempting to simulate this, shown below, but it doesn't recognize the last Column.

```vb
Sub Ls_List_Click()
'variables used in for each loops
Dim Column_Array() As Variant
Dim EndRange As Range

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.Ls_List.Value).Select

Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlRight)).Select

EndRange = Range("A1").End(xlRight).Offset(2, 0)

Range(EndRange, EndRange.End(xlRight)).Select
EndRange = EndRange.End(xlRight).Offset(2, 0)

Column_Array() = EndRange

'... couple of for each loops

End Sub
```

I get error 1004 on the following line:

```vb
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlRight)).Select
```

Comment: You need `Set` for Object variables, i.e. `EndRange`.

Comment: `xlToRight` would be correct syntax

Comment: What are the `.select` statements even being used for?  there is no reference to `.selection`, and each `set endrange` refinds those points.  Seems like those could be removed completely and this would still work.  And `endrange` is just finding the last column then offsetting two rows down; is this the goal?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `xlRight` with `xlToRight` you should be good

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something more like:

```
Sub Ls_List_Click()
'variables used in for each loops
Dim Column_Array() As Variant

Column_Array() = Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1, Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column)).value

'... couple of for each loops

End Sub
```

There didn't appear to be rhyme or reason for the `.select` components beyond stepping through to see where things were (nice for testing... i guess?).

Just one line of code gets your array generated for all the contiguous headers in your first row.

---

**Edit:**

Checking back, because `EndRange` is used for looping, you may want to write:

```
Sub Ls_List_Click()
'variables used in for each loops
Dim Column_Array() As Variant, EndRange as Long 'reference to column number, not a range, so watch referencing

EndRange = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
Column_Array() = Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1, EndRange)).value

'... couple of for each loops

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Two main issues with your code:

1. You misspelled `xlRight` - the correct value is `xlToRight`. That's why it is recommended to use `Option Explicit`, so such errors are detected at compile time.
2. You shouldn't use `Select` - what for? If you want to reference particular cells/range, just use `Cells(row, column)` (`row` and `column` are integers) or `Range("A1:B3")` (just example).

Having said that, to get values into an array, you should use:

```
firstRowArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Value2
```

Expalnation:

I used `Range` overload, accepting two cells as top-left and bottom-right cells to define the range. Top left is `Cell(1, 1)`, i.e. `A1` and bottom left is `Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)`, which you are already familiar with :)

Then I use `Value2` property, which return array of values (you could use `Value` but it's slower).

Note that, the result will be **two-diensional** array with number of rows and number of columns same as in the range.